# Convert JSON date in the "mm dd yyyy" format

Tags: android, json

In my application the Date Fiend JSON response comes as this type:

```
 "CreatedOn": "\/Date(1313572467987+0000)\/"
```

I want to convert this date in the "MM DD YYYY" format. How can I convert this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That date in your JSON response looks like a standard timestamp (e.g. number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970). If you parse out the timestamp something like:

```
    String timestamp = jsonValue.split("\\(")[1].split("\\+")[0];
    Date createdOn = new Date(Long.parseLong(timestamp));
```

Now you can use SimpleDateFormat to format a date string:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yyyy");
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(createdOn);
```

This is ignoring the timezone adjustment in that response (the '+0000') you might also want to parse out this value and add/remove the hours from your timestamp value before formatting..

Comment: Its giving me error......06-03 16:21:30.327: W/System.err(30621): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "1433315147570)/".......seems error in split function param.

Comment: String timestamp = jsonValue.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");..............had to do this instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [**SimpleDateFormat**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), so just try to search on the same.

Detailed example is here: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/date-handling-android-development