# Date format retrieved from a service

Tags: java, javascript, android, json

I'm working on getting Json objects from a service to a List View in Android... the date format looks like this "/Date(1354222800000+0300)/" ... how can I change it to a readable format?

```
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);
    map.put("mDate", "" + e.getString("mDate"));
    mylist.add(map);

}
```

Comment: is there on documentation what this format means? [+0300 quite sure means GMT + 3h]

Comment: use "substring" to extract the datetimemillis (always 13 numbers) or use regexp.

Comment: i found this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103792/convert-json-date-in-the-mm-dd-yyyy-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String mDate = getFormattedDate(e.getString("JSON OBJECT"));

    private String getFormattedDate(String stringDate) throws JSONException {
    String strDate = stringDate.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");

    strDate = strDate.substring(0, strDate.indexOf("+"));
    Long longDate = Long.parseLong(strDate, 10);
    Date mDate = new Date(longDate);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(mDate);

    return formattedDate;
}
```

Comment: This is how i found a solution to format a JSON Date to a readable format, :) :) :)

Comment: JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);

Answer (score 0):

This is the MS JSON date format.

Use:

```
var myDate = new Date(parseInt(String(dateString).substr(6)));
```

Comment: yeah, i know it in java script :) but im new in android development and i want to change the format into java... thanks for your answer